# Enter a date into an empty cell (G2), populate another empty cell (H2) with +12 days

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need G2 and H2 to remain empty until I enter a date in G2

I have tried =G2+12, this would have to be entered each time I enter a date. I need my user to enter a date into (G2) that will populate into H2. I would like the (H2) date to be a red font.

Answer (score 0):

In H2 enter this formula

`=iferror(if(iSBlank(G2),"",Date(year(G2),month(G2),Day(G2)+12)),"")`.

In H2 you get new date.

- For example if G2 has 01/01/2022 then in H2 you get 13/01/2022 ,,
  remember the Date format is dd/mm/yyyy, if you are using US date
  format mm/dd/yyyy then modify the formula accordingly.
- IFERROR is been used in case accidentally if you enter TEXT in G2,
  formula will return BLANK.

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement that H2 needs to remain empty until G2 has a date. It's also totally unnecessary and convoluted to nest these formulas. Just add the number of days to the date.

Comment: **"I need G2 and H2 to remain empty until I enter a date in G2"**, this is what the OP is looking for,, ultimately wants to add 12 days ,,, my formula needs little modification,,, to check whether G2 is BLANK or not,, if not BLANK then add days,, thanks for prompting,,, in fact in anticipation of OP/READRES good understanding I've skipped that part !!

Comment: Still, the `Date(Year(),Month(),Day()+n)` approach is way more complicated than it needs to be. Just `G2+n`, man. Checking with IsBlank will also cause an error when text is entered in G2.

Comment: @teylyn ,, thanks again,,, look there is always space for improvisation,,, now considering the OP's understanding and the level of the question,,, I though using simplest method will help the OP first to realize the mechanism,,, which is the most important for the OP,,, since struggling with the BLANK/EMPTY cell,,,, justify whether the entered value is TEXT/NUMBER should be a bounce,,,,  DATE is basic function explains how to add value to DAYs ☺☺

Comment: @teylyn ,,, and one more crucial issue,,, U know better if once in cell DATE is entered and then after replaced by any NUMBER ,, like 1000 , XL converts it into the DATE,,, and in this situation even ISNUMBER will not trap it & add 12 to the DAY,,, and after every entry no one  wish to reformat the cell into TEXT and others,,,,  so the conclusion is,, in certain situation one has to compromise ,,, a wise move ☺☺☺

Comment: Not sure what you are driving at. Are you trying to tell me that your approach will only work if G2 contains a date and it will ignore a number? Well, no, it won't. Your formula is simply more complicated than it needs to be. You only got it to do what the question asked for after I pointed you to a logic error.  It's very easy to explain that Excel stores dates as numbers and that you can simply add numbers to a date to add days. Read my post.  That's easier to understand than a convoluted construct like the one you offered.

Comment: @teylyn ,,,  what I was trying,, even the ISNUMBER doesn't works properly,,, U know better but let me tell Y,, if in G2 1st enter `01/01/2022` a valid date,,, formula in H2 returns `13/01/2022` ,,, next in G2 enter 100,, getting `09/04/1900' since it's a NUMBER is been tested by the ISNUMBER,, so XL will add 12 and return `21/04/1900` ,,, is not the date OP was expecting ,,,, since OP emphasis on EMPTY so that I've suggested ISBLANK ,,, which one of the simplest approach,,,  and nothing more,,,, have nice weekend ☺

Comment: But your formula with IsBlank will also produce the result 21/4/1900 if you enter a 100 into G2. So what's your point? Also, your formula will return an error if text is entered into G2. Using IsNumber, this error can be avoided.

Comment: @teylyn ,, you know better this is the BUG while validate the DATE in XL,,,, avoid the error while entering Text , iferror can be used,,,  so the conclusion is what we both suggested creates problem in certain situations,,, No win No loss,,, so better assume or suggest the OP/community to avoid entering Text or Number ,,, only DAte and nothing,, ☺☺☺

Comment: Let me explain it in simple words: Your formula is more complicated and it returns an error for text. My formula is simpler and does not retun an error for text. Otherwise, the results are the same. I consider a simpler formula with no error output a better solution.

Comment: @teylyn  ,,, that has been fixed ,,, included IFERROR,,, I think we have discussed almost every aspect,, nothing left,,, now instead of pulling the topic towards unproductive discussion better settle down ,,, and look forward for the next,,, if U feel we may continue exchanging views and other through mail ,, till then ☺☺

Comment: Can you see how your formula is way more complex than it needs to be? Now it does everything my formula does, but with three times as much complication and longer calculation time. Why would ANYONE suggest that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a worksheet function to write a value into a different cell.

If you want cell H2 to appear blank, unless G2 has a date, then you need a formula that checks G2 and then acts accordingly. For example with something like this in cell H2:

```
=if(isnumber(G2),G2+12,"")
```

To Excel, all dates are numbers, starting with 1 = 1/1/1900. So, if G2 has a number, then add 12 to that number, otherwise display a blank cell.